# DLL should not be visible in VS solution explorer

Tags: solution-explorer

I noticed that some dlls I included as content in my csproj appear at the root of the project in Visual studio in the solution explorer. Not only there, but also under all projects that referer to this project. Is there any way to make them invisible ?

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="librdkafka\x64\librdkafka.dll" Visible="false">
  <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
</Content>
```

[image: dll visible]

Comment: It is a simple way to ensure those unmanaged DLLs get copied into the build directory.  Another way to do it is to use xcopy.exe in a post-build event.  It only actually matters for the .exe project.

Comment: The project ends up being published as a nuget, so I don't know how that would work for this copy idea.

Comment: also,  I don't understand why the content files must appear at the root of the project. I'd be happy if they were inside a folder, as they physically are.